# I am switching hosts but keeping the same domain name. How do I redirect the old urls to the new urls when the old host will no longer be supporting?

Tags: wordpress

I have a domain that I'm moving from one host to another host. (e.g. example.com hosted by eCreative, to be hosted on Siteground instead.)

I want to redirect the old URLs (eCreative) to the new URLs (Siteground) even after when the old host is gone so there are no broken links. The first host uses some kind of platform - I don't know what. But the new host is WordPress. The first host will not give me access to any backend other than a very limited admin portal. But I have full access on siteground.

I do not want to send these old urls to 404 pages.

I've heard about using .htaccess but the two websites do not use the same .htaccess. So I don't know how I can use this for redirecting the old urls to the new urls.

If anyone can give me an idea of how to resolve this issue, that would be wonderful.

Comment: How are your URLs changing? Examples?

Comment: example.com/product-p123 to example.com/product

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the host changing but the domain name is staying the same you wont have a problem? Eg `example.com/about` on first host is still `example.com/about` on the second host, it's just the IP behind the scenes that is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Your site/page urls would not have taken into account your web host and its urls. Well not unless your pages were been served from a sub domain from the webhost eg robson.textfixtures.com  or a sub level like textfixtures.com/robson. I seriously doubt this is your case.

If you are serving from your own domain namespace then you have nothing to worry about regarding changing urls.

Your biggest worry will be to ensure.

1. Your content is properly migrated to the new web host.
2. Ensure your dns records are properly update to point to the IP of the server hosting your site(name server update).

Comment: I do also have a subdomain that I'm reintegrating onto the site so some pages will be going from subdomain.example.com to example.com/subdomain

Comment: in that case it also depends on how subdomain.example.com was served. most things should've been coded relative to documentroot in which case everything would all work regardless of the backend changes.